# How to get several combinations of documents where sums of properties reach a certain value in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

If we imagine this kind of document structure :

```js
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "",
    values : {
      a: 24,
      b: 42
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "",
    values : {
      a: 43,
      b: 53
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "",
    values : {
      a: 33,
      b: 25
    }
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "",
    values : {
      a: 89,
      b: 2
    }
  }
  // ...
]
```

Is it possible to get one or more lists of documents where, for example, the sum of the `$.values.a` equals 100 and the sum of the `$.values.b` equals 120? Or if not is it possible to sort the bests fits with a kind of threshold?

For example, the best output can be something like that :

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "",
    values : {
      a: 24,
      b: 42
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "",
    values : {
      a: 43,
      b: 53
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "",
    values : {
      a: 33,
      b: 25
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: What do you mean `sum`? whats the field you want to group by? `name`?

Comment: Hum no it's more like finding the bests combinations that let's the addition of all `values.a` and all the `values.b` reaching the nearest desired values. So here in my exemple, I want to find the best list of documents where the addition of all the values.a of the documents contained into the list is equal to 100 and the same for values.b but for 120. Is more clear? Quite complicated to explain sorry

Answer (score 1):

### There is no any native implementation...

But, You can have desired results if your data meets some requirements:

1. You collection has no too much data (this solution scales badly)
2. Your `id` field is unique
3. Your collection has index for `id` field

---

### Explanation

1. We sort by `id`
2. With `$lookup` with the same `collection` (it's important ´id´ to be indexed) and pick next 10 documents for the current document L <sub>i</sub>=(Doc <sub>i+1</sub> ... Doc <sub>i+11</sub>)
3. With `$reduce`, we count from <sub>i</sub> ... <sub>i+n</sub> untill `a > 100` and `b > 120`
4. With `$facet`, we separate lists which meets exactly `a=100`, `b=120` results (**equals**) and *threshold* (+- 10 for `values.a` and `values.b`)
5. Last steps, if any **equals** exists, we ignore *threshold*. Otherwise, we take *threshold*.

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      id: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      let: {
        id: "$id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $sort: {
            id: 1
          }
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $gt: [
                "$id",
                "$$id"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 10
        }
      ],
      as: "bucket"
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$bucket",
          initialValue: {
            a: "$values.a",
            b: "$values.b",
            data: [
              {
                _id: "$_id",
                id: "$id",
                name: "$name",
                values: "$values"
              }
            ]
          },
          in: {
            a: {
              $add: [
                "$$value.a",
                {
                  $cond: [
                    {
                      $and: [
                        {
                          $lt: [
                            "$$value.a",
                            100
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          $lt: [
                            "$$value.b",
                            120
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "$$this.values.a",
                    0
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            b: {
              $add: [
                "$$value.b",
                {
                  $cond: [
                    {
                      $and: [
                        {
                          $lt: [
                            "$$value.a",
                            100
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          $lt: [
                            "$$value.b",
                            120
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "$$this.values.b",
                    0
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            data: {
              $concatArrays: [
                "$$value.data",
                {
                  $cond: [
                    {
                      $and: [
                        {
                          $lt: [
                            "$$value.a",
                            100
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          $lt: [
                            "$$value.b",
                            120
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    [
                      "$$this"
                    ],
                    []
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      equals: [
        {
          $match: {
            a: 100,
            b: 120
          }
        }
      ],
      threshold: [
        {
          $match: {
            a: {
              $gte: 90,
              $lt: 110
            },
            b: {
              $gte: 110,
              $lt: 130
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      result: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $gt: [
              {
                $size: "$equals"
              },
              0
            ]
          },
          "$equals",
          "$threshold"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$result"
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z0JHPef-nzJ)